# Exibir um GIF pelo início

Tags: html

### Cenário

Tenho **uma página** que contém uma `div` onde o conteúdo é carregado por JQuery e uma `div` oculta (`hidden`), com um GIF:

```
<div id="lista"></div>

<div id="loading" hidden>
    <img src="loading.gif"/>
</div>
```

Nesta página, tenho um **botão "Atualizar"** (funcionando perfeitamente), que chama um método *JQuery*, e executa os passos :

1. Quando executa para atualizar a lista, oculta-se a `div` da lista e exibe a `div` com o gif.
2. Tendo o retorno, faz o processo inverso.

*Simplesmente exibe o GIF enquanto aguarda o processamento e retorno da "lista" (extremamente comum)*.

---

### O "problema"

**O GIF ele tem "começo/meio/fim"**. Vamos supor que ele exibe "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10" num intervalo 10 segundos.

As vezes eu aperto o botão "Atualizar" e ele não começa do início, e sim onde estiver naquele momento (já que ele está lá, mas a `div` só está oculta).

---

### Pergunta

**Gostaria** de saber, se existe uma forma de "ver o GIF" pelo início, ou seja, **sempre que ele for exibido, ele começar novamente**.

---

*Não sei se isso teria que recarregá-lo novamente, ou como fazer isso.*

Comment: Eu acho que uma solução mais gráfica seja melhor do que mexer no play do gif. Que tal tornar as imagens do gif de forma a ser independente do momento de exibição? Como um `spinner`?

Comment: As vezes vc pode ter duas imagens iguais, e quando vc muda o evento vc troca a imagem por outra igual, assim teoricamente deveria começar do 0, já que acabou de ser chamada outra img pelo ajax, ou algo assim... Não sei se com ajax vc consegue fazer um refresh só na imagem...

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado spinner seria um "carrousel"? Sei o que é no Android, no HTML não 

Comment: @hugocsl Mas aí eu teria 2 img com hidden!? Não daria na mesma?

Comment: Estava pensando em criar uma outra página, só com o GIF, e chamá-la no local da lista enquanto ela é gerada. Teoricamente estou carregando novamente, e assim iniciando o GIF, correto!? Mas teria download do GIF toda vez!?

Comment: Cara na verdade a intenção é que vc tire uma imagem e inclua outra "nova", pois se vc chama a mesma imagem, ela não faz o refresh e vai aparecer com a animação de onde estiver e não do início.  A ideia da página ele legal tb, acredito que não faria download toda vez não pq ela viria do cache local e não do servidor

Comment: @hugocsl Quando vc diz 2 imagens, não seriam 2 `div`? Se ela ficar em cache, mesmo assim seria uma nova chamada, acho que iria dar certo né...

Comment: Não seria dois .gif diferentes mesmo... mas não sei se daria certo é só uma ideia. Quando vc faz a requisição da imagem, mesmo se ela estiver no cache ele deveria começar do início, mas tem que ser a requisição, só esconder e mostrar com display ou opacity não deve dar certo...

Comment: Entendi... Sei pouco de JS, então não consigo imaginar como seriam 2 GIF. Na minha cabeça está assim: eu teria a `div` que uso pra dar `.show` e `.hide`, e dentro 2 tag `img`, com os GIF, e cada hora exibo 1 deles de forma intercalada. Ahh.. não sei.. hahah 

Comment: Troca a url da imagem passando um parametro ficticio ".png?t=2342" sendo o valor de T um num randomico e ve se o gif reinicia sem vc ter que remover o elemento DOM e incluir de novo.

Comment: @RBoschini Não funcionou!

Comment: Coloque o `loading.gif` como background no css e quando atualizar você manipula a classe do elemento com `addclass` e ao final, basta remover a classe.

Comment: Outra solução seria você deixar o "src" do gif em branco ou nulo, e quando você executa o seu "Atualizar", a "src" é corrigida, junto com os atributos de estilo de visibilidade ou display. Existem também soluções como [libgif-js](https://github.com/buzzfeed/libgif-js) e [x-gif](https://github.com/geelen/x-gif) para você controlar como os gifs são executados.